# JQuery absolute position working bad in Chrome (but OK in Firefox)

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox, data-visualization

I'm creating a data visualization using babbles with absolute position in responsive design. So I need to place them using a percentage, and then a value in px in order to place the center of the bubble (and not a corner) in the place indicated.
As the CSS calc won't work in mobile platforms, I do it with jQuery

```
bubblecorr = '-=' + (sizePcts[h]*bubblesize)*0.5 + 'px';
$("#b"+h).css('left', horPcts[h]+'%').css('left', bubblecorr);
$("#b"+h).css('bottom', verPcts[h]+'%').css('bottom', bubblecorr);
```

Where bubblecorr is the correction in pixels for the radius of the bubble, sizePcts the size of it (from Array and corrected to use radius and not total size), horPcts the % X-axis value abd verPcts the % Y-axis value. I guess you can imagine this is inside a loop.

The weird thing is this: first and second line works great in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. The third one (bottom reposition) ONLY WORKS IN FIREFOX (in Safari and Chrome skips the % value and just use the px value).

Any idea why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: have u tried combining the assignments? `.css({left:horPcts[h]+'%',bottom:verPcts[h]+'%'});`?

Comment: @Pointy, in fact, it works for the left (and everything in Firefox), so it's possible. The weird thing is it's working fro left and not for bottom.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey Same result... Works in Firefox, only the left in Chrome... :/

Comment: @ChiquiEsteban OK I see that you're actually updating it to a relative offset.

Comment: can u set up a quick jsFiddle?

Comment: Quite complex for being quick... but maybe you can use this: http://chiquiesteban.com/test.html

Comment: I think you may use offset property to do so in All browsers as follows.

 1. find the offset of an element above which this is being placed
 2. add to left offset a value which you use for centering the Element